# Center a paragraph element when text wraps without centering the text using flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Before this gets down-voted into oblivion, let me say I've searched through the numerous SO questions that looked similar to this one, but none that I found addressed my issue.

I'm using flexbox to center some `<p>` tags both horizontally and vertically within an element.  I *don't* want to center the text within the `<p>` element, just center the `<p>` elements themselves.

```css
.app-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.app p {
  display: inline-block;
}

.title-bar {
  background-color: #202225;
  color: #72767D;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0 2px 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-outer">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <span class="draggable">Skipwars</span>
    <span class="btns">
      <button id="btn-minimize" tabindex="-1">-</button><!--
      --><button id="btn-close" tabindex="-1">&times;</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="app">
    <p>Add a browser source pointed at <!--<a href="#">http://localhost:3333/</a>--></p>
    <p>
      Optional parameter <code style="display:inline">threshold=n</code>. ex: <a
        href="#">http://localhost:3333/?threshold=4</a> (default 8)
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

My app is 300px wide (I'm using electron).

[image: Image of app]

As you can see, if the paragraph doesn't have enough text for multiple lines, it works fine.  If it does, the paragraph expands to the width of `.app`, and the text is left-justified.

This is what I'm looking for:

[image: Desired result]

I thought that setting the paragraphs' `display` to `inline-block` would do the trick, but it doesn't.

Comment: Did you try giving the `p` elements `text-align: left`?

Comment: I just tried.  It didn't work.

Comment: Nope just text align "center" does the trick. https://codepen.io/CedGrvl/pen/GRRPLjb @dx_over_dt

Comment: Unset, but it's acting like it's the full width.

Comment: @CedricGourville I *don't* want the text centered within the paragraph elements.  I want the paragraph elements centered.

Comment: I've edited the OP to include a desired result img

Answer (score 2):

It's working as expected, but since the `<p>` tags are the same width as the viewport, they are flush to the left when the vp is too small, and in this case the url is so long that it wraps to the next line and leaves a space on the first, making it appear that it is not centered. I added some horizontal padding to the `<p>` tags to better illustrate:

```css
.app-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.app p {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.title-bar {
  background-color: #202225;
  color: #72767D;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0 2px 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="app-outer">
  <div class="title-bar">
    <span class="draggable">Skipwars</span>
    <span class="btns">
      <button id="btn-minimize" tabindex="-1">-</button><!--
      --><button id="btn-close" tabindex="-1">&times;</button>
    </span>
  </div>
  <div class="app">
    <p>Add a browser source pointed at
      <!--<a href="#">http://localhost:3333/</a>--></p>
    <p>
      Optional parameter <code style="display:inline">threshold=n</code>. ex: <a href="#">http://localhost:3333/?threshold=4</a> (default 8)
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But how do I ignore the space added when the line wraps?  For example, in FB chat, multiple lines don't necessarily make the chat bubble the maximum width.

Comment: If I understand your question, give your p tags a defined width or max-width, and/or give them horizontal padding.

Comment: I want the elements to be sized dynamically in case I add more text.  Setting a width or a max width would prevent this.

Comment: You can use dynamic sizing, e.g. `width: 70%`. Otherwise they will be 100% of their parent container.

Comment: I'm nearly certain that with the proper CSS, they *won't* always be 100% of their parent container.  Like I said, FB chat does it.

Comment: @dx_over_dt The default width of an element is auto, meaning it is the width of the content of the element. If the containing element is more narrow than the width of content of the child element, the child element shrinks to the width of the containing element. Try resizing my example. It does what you show in your desired image.